# Why are my custom headers being overwritten?

Tags: php, email

So I found the below function to send an e-mail. I wrote the two lines after the function to call it based on command line parameters.

```
function mail_file( $to, $subject, $messagehtml, $from, $fileatt, $replyto="" ) {
    // handles mime type for better receiving
    $ext = strrchr( $fileatt , '.');
    $ftype = "";
    if ($ext == ".doc") $ftype = "application/msword";
    if ($ext == ".jpg") $ftype = "image/jpeg";
    if ($ext == ".gif") $ftype = "image/gif";
    if ($ext == ".zip") $ftype = "application/zip";
    if ($ext == ".pdf") $ftype = "application/pdf";
    if ($ftype=="") $ftype = "application/octet-stream";

    // read file into $data var
    $file = fopen($fileatt, "rb");
    $data = fread($file,  filesize( $fileatt ) );
    fclose($file);

    // split the file into chunks for attaching
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    // build the headers for attachment and html
    $h = "From: $from\r\n";
    if ($replyto) $h .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $h .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $h .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $h .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $h .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $h .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $h .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $h .= $messagehtml."\r\n\r\n";
    $h .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $h .= "Content-Type: ".$ftype."; name=\"".basename($fileatt)."\"\r\n";
    $h .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $h .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($fileatt)."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $h .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $h .= "--".$uid."--";

    // send mail
    return mail( $to, $subject, strip_tags($messagehtml), str_replace("\r\n","\n",$h) ) ;


}

$body = file_get_contents($argv[3]);

mail_file($argv[1], $argv[2], $body, $argv[4], $argv[5]);
```

So if I call the above script with the following at the command line...

```
php sendmail.php demo@morningcatch.ph This\ is\ a\ test Content.html bob@fake.org form.pdf
```

Then it sends the mail ok, the attachment gets stuck on, the subject is "This is a test" and the body has the contents of Content.html... The only thing not working is that it still shows the e-mail as stemming from "root@mybox" instead of bob@fake.org

If it makes a difference, I'm trying to send the mail from a VM through a NAT connection on my laptop. Could that be causing an issue? Would it be better if I bridged it somehow? (Which I've never managed to get working...) The headers the receiver is actually seeing are as follows

```
Return-Path: <root@mybox>
Received: from mybox (Hostlaptop.local [hostIP])
by morningcatch.ph (8.14.3/8.14.3/Debian-9.lubuntul)) with SMTP id blahblah
for <demo@morningcatch.ph>: Current date
Message-Id: Gibberish

From: "root" <root@mybox>
Date: Date received
To: demo@morningcatch.ph
Subject: This is a test
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:sendemail.php
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multi-part/mixed; boundary="hash"
```

So on and so forth. I don't THINK it's something with the mail server, because my boss wrote a python script that does close to the same thing (though he couldn't get the attachment to work) and it spoofs the sending e-mail address just fine. Which now that I think about it, makes me think it isn't the VM, since that python script works fine from my box as well. Why won't my php script do it? Any thoughts?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the issue. Same code, same command line parameters (except the domain name) and it is working just fine on my server.

Comment: Hmmm, then it must be something environmental rather than with my script? Wonder how to track that down... Grrr. Thanks for checking though

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code both on my local machine and on server side, and it works just like it should.

Here are the headers from the test ran on my local machine:

```
Received: from Raidmax (unknown [<my local ip>])
    (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    by <myserver> (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 883B94796A
    for <stanimir@<mydomain>>; Thu, 30 Oct 2014 21:21:52 +0000 (UTC)
Received: from Raidmax (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by Raidmax (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-8) with ESMTP id s9ULRaij008312
    for <stanimir@<mydomain>>; Thu, 30 Oct 2014 23:27:36 +0200
Received: (from stoyanov@localhost)
    by Raidmax (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id s9ULRa8L008257;
    Thu, 30 Oct 2014 23:27:36 +0200
Date: Thu, 30 Oct 2014 23:27:36 +0200
Message-Id: <201410302127.s9ULRa8L008257@Raidmax>
To: stanimir@<mydomain>
Subject: This is a test
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:tmp.php
From: bob@fake.org
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

If you're using Linux, /var/log/mail.* is a good place to start. `From:` headers are usually handled by the sender.

Comment: mail.err and mail.warn are empty, mail.log and mail.info both contain a bunch of entries that look like `Date mybox sSMTP[3299]: Sent mail for arpwatch@mybox (221 2.0.0 morningcatch.ph closing connection) uid=108 username =arpwatch outbytes=521`